# Fluent Validation For Azure Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, fluentvalidation

Below is Example I am using to create function and trying to validate the models using Fluent Validation. Their are 2 Different Function TestUser and AdminUser for both i am writing class to check the validation. Is their any other efficient approach to create genralized method for these model validation?

```
[FunctionName("TestUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostTestUser(
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "api/v1/Test")][RequestBodyType(typeof(TestUser)] TestUser testUser)
        {
           TestUserValidator validator = new TestUserValidator();
           var validatedTestUser = validator.Validate(testUser);
           if (!validatedTestUser.IsValid)
            return BadRequestResponse(validatedTestUser);
        }

public class TestUser 
    {        
        [JsonProperty("Id", Order = 1)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("name", Order = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 public class TestUserValidator : AbstractValidator<TestUser>
    {       
        public TestUserValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(_=> _.Id).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").CheckGuid();
            RuleFor(_=> _.Name).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().WithMessage("NameRequired");
        }
```

```
[FunctionName("AdminUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAdminUser (
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "api/v1/admin")][RequestBodyType(typeof(AdminUser)] AdminUser adminUser )
        {
           AdminUserValidator validator = new AdminUserValidator();
           var validatedAdminUser = validator.Validate(adminUser);
           if (!validatedAdminUser.IsValid)
            return BadRequestResponse(validatedAdminUser);
        }

public class AdminUser 
    {        
        [JsonProperty("Id", Order = 1)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("admin_name", Order = 2)]
        public string AdminName{ get; set; }
    }

public class AdminUserValidator: AbstractValidator<AdminUser>
    {       
        public AdminUserValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(_=> _.Id).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().WithMessage(Resources.FieldRequired).CheckGuid();
            RuleFor(_=> _.AdminName).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().WithMessage("AdminNameRequired");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Function Filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1284) feature is best suited for this but it's still in preview (not recommended for production).

The simplest approach would be to [leverage DI](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/di.html) and inject validators into your class instead of initializing one for each invocation.

Another approach you could consider simplifying your code would be to have an extension method that you can call on your objects to validate them.

Here is one way you can set that up

##### IValidateable

```cs
public interface IValidateable<T>
{
    AbstractValidator<T> Validator { get; }
}
```

##### ValidationExtensions

```cs
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValid<T>(this IValidateable<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Validator.Validate((T)obj).IsValid;
    }
}
```

##### Model - Person and PersonValidator

```cs
public class Person : IValidateable<Person>
{
    [JsonProperty("Id", Order = 1)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name", Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public AbstractValidator<Person> Validator { get => PersonValidator.Instance; }
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public static PersonValidator Instance = new PersonValidator();

    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(_ => _.Id).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().WithMessage("Required");
        RuleFor(_ => _.Name).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).NotNull().WithMessage("NameRequired");
    }
}
```

#### Function

```cs
public static class PersonFunctions
{
    [FunctionName("CreatePerson")]
    public static IActionResult CreatePerson(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] Person person,
        ILogger log)
    {
        if (!person.IsValid())
            return new BadRequestResult();

        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a good way to implement the !person.IsValid() part in a filter, automating all validation before the function is executed? I already found a good way of returning a badrequest from the filter. Only thing left is triggering the validation in the filter.